# Using Cordova plugin in Ionic React project without ionic-native

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have project with Ionic + React + Capacitor + TypeScript an i want use com.batch.cordova plugin for push notification.
Batch.com has sample for integration of Batch and Cordova (https://doc.batch.com/cordova/advanced/ionic), but it is not useful for me.
I have installed plugin:

```
npm i com.batch.cordova
```

When i import plugin, i receive error **ReferenceError: cordova is not defined**

```
import "../node_modules/com.batch.cordova/www/batch"
```

How can i integrate this module with my project?

Comment: is this when you test on device? also that import looks incorrect

Comment: No when i test on web.